# Traverse through an array with missing elements and report those missing elements in shell

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Consider the ideal array to be :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Say the array that i get during one execution:

```
0 1 3 5
```

My script should display 2 and 4 are missing . 
My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
## declare an array variable
a=`cat read/Array/values/from file/`
declare -a simpleArray=( $a )
# get length of an array
arraylength=${#simpleArray[@]}
j=0
while [ $j -lt $arraylength ]
do
# use for loop to read all values and indexes
for ((i=1;i< ${arraylength}+1;i++));
do
y=${simpleArray[$i-1]}
echo $y'current value'
if [ y == j  ]
then 
echo 'present'
else
echo $j'not present'
j=$((j+1))
fi
done
echo 'for loop close'
done
echo 'while loop close'
```

EDIT Code

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`cat /home/muzammilm/textdate.txt`
simpleArray=( 1 2 6 )
j=0;
i=0;
arraylength=${#simpleArray[@]}
echo $arraylength
while [ $j != 6 ]
do
for (( i=0; i< $arraylength; i++ ))
do
if [ ${simpleArray[$i]} = $j ]
then
break
elif [ ${simpleArray[$i]} > $j ]
then
echo $j'not present'
break;
fi
done
j=$((j+1))
done
```

This gives me an error,though it works perfectly when the ip array contain only two elements

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how do i get about getting the op as" 2 and 4 are missing ". so far the code displays 0current value
0not present
1current value
1not present
2current value
2not present
3current value
3not present
4current value
4not present
5current value
5not present
for loop close
while loop close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test is *always false*:

```
 if [ y == j  ]
```

because it is a string comparison of constant strings "y" and "j". Did you mean

```
 if [ $y = $j  ]
```

instead? (Yes, only one `=` sign is the correct test for equality).

Comment: true i did miss those $ signs . though im still unable to get the O/P. I made some changes to code as follows :

Comment: #!/bin/bash
a=`cat /home/muzammilm/textdate.txt`
simpleArray=( 1 2 6 )
j=0;
i=0;
arraylength=${#simpleArray[@]}
echo $arraylength
while [ $j != 6 ]
do
for (( i=0; i<$arraylength; i++ ))
do
if [ ${simpleArray[$i]} = $j ]
then
break
elif [ ${simpleArray[$i]} > $j ]
then
echo $j'not present'
break;
fi
done
j=$((j+1))
done

Comment: @MuzammilH.Momin You can't use `>` as greater-than (it is a shell redirection operator). You need to use `if [ "$x" -gt "$y" ]; then ...`.

Comment: that was perfect and the code works flawlessly now. Thank you so much

Comment: @MuzammilH.Momin Good! The next step on Stackoverflow is to *accept* this answer by clicking the check symbol to the left. Accepting will earn you two credits.